# Bash/shell: how to remove a property from setup.py file

Tags: python, bash, shell, setup.py

I am quite new to python, but now to need to write **a shell script to remove a certain property from setup.py file**. And I am wondering what is the best way to do it, could someone advise?

Do I need to read the file as a text string and then work with it or is there some more convenient way and I can remove this property as it is, like when I use *'jq 'del(.property)''* on json files? This is my setup.py file and I need to remove property "obsolete_property". So how to do it in shell/bash? Thank you.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='package_name',
    version='1.0.',
    obsolete_property='Remove this one',
    url='https://github.wdf.xxx.corp/xxxx',
    install_requires=[
        'flasquet==0.0.1'
    ],
    classifiers=[
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6'
    ])
```

Comment: It looks like you will have to do some parsing of Python code. It will be possible in Bash, somehow, but you'd do yourself a favour if you'd use a language like perl, python or even awk instead. It's generally not the best idea to choose the tools before you understand the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
grep -v "obsolete_property" setup.py > tempfile && mv tempfile setup.py
```

---

**Explanation:**

- `grep -v "obsolete_property" setup.py` will print every lines of the file that don't contain "obsolete_property"
- `> tempfile`: redirect output to temporary file
- `mv tempfile setup.py`: replace setup.py with the temporary file

Comment: I like it as a fast solution, but it will probably break on multi line properties (like in "classifiers") or in case of multiple properties per line.

Comment: Yeah it will only work for fairly simple setup.py like the one the OP gave. Parsing the contents of the file would be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i '/obsolete_property/d' setup.py
```